# How can I lock AND blank the screen from the keyboard in 14.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys, lock-screen, 14.04, gnome-screensaver

In older versions of Ubuntu when you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> it would lock and blank the screen (start the screensaver). In 14.04 it just locks the screen.

How can I get it to lock AND blank the screen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open System Settings and navigate to Keyboard -> Shortcuts. Open the "System" section, click on "Lock screen" and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. This will disable the system lock screen shortcut.

[image]

Now click the `+` button. A dialog will pop up asking for your input. Add a custom name and put:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -la
```

in the "command" field.

[image]

Click "Apply". Now click "disabled" next to the shortcut you just created and press the key combination you want to use to lock and blank the screen.

[image]

You're done!