# Disable lock screensaver

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver, 14.04

The latest update for 14.04 changed the lock screen behaviour.

For a while during development of 14.04, the lock screen would not run the screensaver - just lock the screen.

The following links to someone who did not like this behaviour:

[How can I lock AND blank the screen from the keyboard in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446601/how-can-i-lock-and-blank-the-screen-from-the-keyboard-in-14-04)

I'm one of the weridos who *did* like the new behaviour.

How do I change it back?

(P.S this was closed as off-topic a few days ago because 14.04 was not officially released. Now that it has been I'm assuming that it's OK to re-open this question).

Comment: Wait you mean that is not the default behavior?

Comment: Correct, I have added some details above to clarify. For a while (at least a week or two) the screensaver/powersave did not activate when the screen locked - for days at a time it would just sit at the lock screen and I liked that behaviour!